# php mysql android app проблема с кодировкой(кириллица)

Tags: php, android, mysql

Есть 2 php файла на серваке.

ПЕРВЫЙ

```
<?php
    define ('hostname','*');
    define ('user','*');
    define ('password','*');
    define ('databasename','*');
    $connect=mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, databasename);
?>
```

ВТОРОЙ

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
        require 'connect.php'; 
        createMessage();
    }

    function createMessage() {
        global $connect;
        $fname_lastname = $_POST["fname_lastname"];
        $query="INSERT IGNORE INTO quest_table (fname_lastname) VALUES ('$fname_lastname');";
        mysqli_query ($connect,$query)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
?>
```

В phpmyadmin выставлена кодировка utf8_general_ci, редактировал в notepad++ UTF8 без BOM, игрался с этими двумя кусками,вставлял туда разного, но толкового ничего не получалось, кириллица отображается загугуленами.Может еще усложняется это тем, что происходит через андроид приложение. Хелп плз)

Comment: проблема точно не на стороне java скрипта, я также отправлял кириллический текст через Postman напрямую в бд, также не отображает корректно.

Comment: Интересно то, что json обьект возвращает отлично, значит проблема лишь в отображении в phpmyadmin выходит) странно как то)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот всегда проще так - всегда всё свое держите в UTF (8 или 16 в зависимости от наличия азии в проекте), чужое конвертируете в него (в UTF можно сконвертить любую кодировку) и проблема исчезает на этапе ее возможного зачатия.

Постарайтесь привести все к одной кодировке и явно ее указывать.
Т.к. андроид взаимодействует по http - передавайте заголовок
"Content-Type: что-то/что-то; charset=utf-8"

Без заголовка проблемы будут иметь спонтанный характер

Comment: Заголовок с указанием кодировки Content-Type  надо передавать и от клиента и от сервера.

Answer (score 4):

В ПЕРВЫЙ добавить строчку

```
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
```